# How to enable FTP on windows server 2012 Azure VM

Tags: azure, ftp, windows-server-2012-r2

I have setup FTP site on windows server 2012 R2 which is hosted as VM on Azure Cloud. I have enabled port 21,22,20 on windows Firewall and also on Azure Portal.I have also tried through custom FTP data ports which i have defined in 'FTP Firewall Settings'

After successful authentication, I am receiving following error while connecting through filezilla and other ftp clients.

Status: Retrieving directory listing...

Is there any work around?

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. When you repost, you should include additional details, such as how you set up your azure inbound security rules (or endpoints, if you're using 'classic' vm vs Resource Manager). Also, you didn't specify whether you set up active or passive ftp. Hard to diagnose without additional details.

Comment: Its classic VM. End point rules has been defined for port 20,21,22 and 10000 and 10001 for data port enabled in FTP Firewall support in IIS Manager.  I have tried with passive ftp